# Run R Script from windows command line with parameters

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am trying to run an Rscript via Excel VBA. The macro will call VBShell and execute the R script.

I also want to pass a few parameters to the command line. Here is a simple version of the code:

```
"C:\Users\myname\Documents\R\R-3.4.2\bin\RScript "D:\Group\Subfolder path1\sub folder path 2\script.R" "D:\Group\Subfolder path1\sub folder path 2\" "raw file one.csv" "raw file two.csv" "raw file three.csv"
```

I ran the above code in the command windows but having issues with spacing. The error is `D:/Group/Subfolder` is not regconised as an internal or external command. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: You are missing a double quote after `RScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command shell window (for instance, by tapping the windows key and typing cmd)

```
D:
cd D:\Group\Subfolder path1
dir /X
```

Now you can see the short name (without a space) for folder `sub folder path 2`.

```
cd ..
dir /X
```

Now you can see the short name (without a space) for folder `sub folder path 1`.

In your command, replace the two names with spaces by their short name.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried your method and it works with the folder directory however, I am still not sure how to deal with the file name. There seems to be no short name for the raw file. Thanks

Comment: On my system, those files would get the 8dot3 filenames `RAWFIL~1.CSV`, `RAWFIL~2.CSV` and `RAWFIL~3.CSV` ... What are the first 4 parameters your R script actually receives?

Comment: Hi Peter, I think sometimes windows just doesnt generate short name for files, folders. Anyway, I found a solution where I passed the double  quote in my VBA script and it works. For example : `rawfile1 = """" & "raw file 1" & """" `